# Logging and Python bokeh compatibility

Tags: python, logging, bokeh

I am using import logging to save changes to my bokeh server and I want to save it to a file with a .log extension, but when I run the bokeh server, the file is not created and the can not save operations to .log file.
There is a part of the code I wrote below.

Could it be that I am making a mistake in the code or bokeh server does it not work in accordance with logging?

```
import logging
LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename = "test.log",
                level = logging.DEBUG,
                format = LOG_FORMAT,
                filemode="w")
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

Comment: What are those lines: `from bokeh.io`, `from bokeh.layouts`, ... ? They shouldn't work at all.

Comment: I actually have a very long code but I cannot share everything here. These are the libraries I use in the code.The code that I wrote is the result,I connect to a server and I perform transactions on that server. However, the operations performed on the server did not record in the .log file.There is not even a file with a .log extension.Is it because of incompatibility between logging and bokeh?Cannot I use logging in bokeh?Please dont get too attached to those from lines. I havent written it in detail.For example: from bokeh.io import curdoc
There is a continuation of each,but I didnt write.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please provide some information on what you have tried so far. Did you try to run the program locally or run the program remotely but without bokeh? Did you try to specify absolute path for your log file? What are your steps to run the program? Try to come up with some minimal reproducible example exposing the same issue.

Comment: I am writing on shell to run this code: bokeh serve --show "url".My goal is to save changes made in this browser to a .log extension.For example, I want to see in my .log extension that I clicked on the animate function.I wrote the code needed for this as logger.debug.But this is not happening.Can I use logging with bokeh?I re-edited the code, you can check again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `bokeh serve %some_python_file%`, the Bokeh server is started right away, but your code is executed only when you actually open the URL that points to the Bokeh document that you fill in that code.

`bokeh serve` configures logging by using `logging.basicConfig` as well, and calling this function again does not override anything - that's just how `logging.basicConfig` works.

Instead of using `logging` directly, you should just create and configure your own logger:

```
LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='test.log', mode='w')
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.info('Hello there')
```

Answer (score 1):

Eugene's answer is correct. Calling `logging.basicConfig()` for a second time does not have any effect. Nevertheless, if you are using python >= 3.8 then you can use `force=True` which will disable all existing logging handlers and setup a new one. This practically means that your own `logging.basicCOnfig()` will just work:

```py
logging.basicConfig(..., force=True)
```

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)